# Unit Testing JDBC methods with MySQL specific queries

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, continuous-integration

I have a bunch of methods which run mysql specific SQLs using JDBC calls. I need to write unit or integration test for these methods that should run as part of the CI build.

Currently I'm using an in-memory hsql DB to do unit testing on the database, which obviously isn't compatible with these MySQL specific queries. I end up running my tests against a local mysql instance.

As expected this is leading to drop in code coverage and  code being dropped to production without automated testing.

What are my options here apart from using a central MySQL instance to run these tests?

Sample method for reference -

```
public void bulkLoad(Connection connection) {
      String bulkLoadQuery = "LOAD DATA CONCURRENT LOCAL INFILE ? REPLACE INTO TABLE my_table (id, name)"
      try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement( bulkLoadQuery ) {
          statement.setString( 1, fileToUpload );
          statement.execute();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should *always* use the same database for testing, development, and production.  Not doing so will lead to predicaments such as your current one.  That being said, if the purpose of your tests in fact is to test that the database be working correctly, then, strictly speaking, your tests are not unit tests but rather integration tests.

For unit tests, you would typically mock out all the database calls.  Doing this makes the assumption that in production the database would be behaving correctly, and would let your test focus on some logical piece of code.  In any case, the database is most of the time a single point of failure, and should it go down, your whole system would be crippled.

If you really want to integration test your database, then setup some CRUD tests against it, but don't mingle these tests with the unit tests designed to vet your application code.

Comment: Yes understand these are not pure unit tests and are in theory integration tests. One of the problems with mocking these calls is that these methods do nothing much apart from calling the database, which makes mocking them a futile exercise.

Comment: ...it's not futile if what you are trying to test is the functionality of some unit of your Java code.  Typically, you should validate your database separately, and not at the same time as your code unit tests.

Comment: Yes, understand that. I meant of the Java code isn't doing much apart from the JDBC call. These tests will have very limited value. 

Let me rephrase my question. What if I want to do integration tests? Is running it against the a MySQL DB is the only choice? Thanks for all your inputs